# How can I conect multiple imap accounts to the same ost file?

Tags: imap, shared

I'm sure this has been asked but I cannot file a solution.  I have 3 imap email accounts, let's say a@domain.com, b@domain.com, and c@domain.com. I would like each email account to store its data in a single ost file.  And I'd like to set the name of the ost file to something like domain.ost.  How can I do this?

I tried to find a way to change the inbox for the imap accounts but was not successful  Nor was I able connect the imap accounts to an ost file I created.

Comment: This is a Q&A site for programming questions. Is this a programming question?